# Start the process WindowServer per Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I have to start the WindowServer Via the Terminal:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/WindowServer
```

I can not use

```
killall -HUP WindowServer
```

because the process is not running.
Can it without reboot the system?

Comment: Can You give more details? What do You want to achieve by starting WindowServer process from Terminal?

Comment: We can not work with Apple Remote Desktop ARD. And we need the process WindwoServer, if we want to connect with ARD to the server. Or which process must be running.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand What You mean, but: It's not only WindowServer process. Whole user session must be running in order to do this. But from OSX 10.7 You can start "virtual" GUI session right from the ScreenSharing.app. Starting new "virtual" LoginWindow  session, is made by a private API, here's my stackoverflow question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543752/starting-new-background-gui-login-session-or-loginwindow-on-os-x-cgscreatelogin

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I do not understand it. 
Our problem is that we unable to log us on the server with ARD. 
In the test with our test server we have found if we restart the process, the Login with ARD works again. 
But the process is not running on the live server, we need this only restart. But with what command?

Comment: @Tom it is propbaly better to ask how to fix the problem you see not take a guess as to what might be a fix i.e. to fix your ARD issue you don't need to start WindowServer from a terminal

Comment: …ok i have found it  
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3466991?tstart=0

`launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.WindowServer.plist`
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.WindowServer.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3466991?tstart=0

launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.WindowServer.plist  
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.WindowServer.plist